# Serious confusion with the chain rule

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $x'=x$ and $y'=y-ax$  for some nonzero constant $a$. Then the chain rule states that

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}+\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}= -a\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}$.

Here I have a serious confusion. Since $x'=x$, isn't it that $\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}=0$? However this conclusion is absurd because $\frac{\partial y'}{\partial y'}=1$ What is wrong? I am extremely confused....

Comment: I'm very confused.  Is $x'$ a function?  Is it the derivative of a function?  Are you using the same symbol for both the variable and the function?  What is $\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}$?  This looks like an operator to me, not a fixed constant...

Comment: You have $\partial \over \partial x$... what are you partially differentiating?

Comment: I am just thinking of the operators.

Comment: x, y  and x',y' are just different coordinates of the real plane. I am thinking of the coordinate transform

Comment: I am confused by your last paragraph. What exactly is your question?

Comment: $\frac {\partial} {\partial {y'} }\neq 0 $ it will depend on what you differentiate

Comment: But the above chain rule seems to imply that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} =0$ for any function $f :\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$... What is wrong?

Comment: I think the introduction of $x'$ and $y'$ is an invitation to misunderstanding.  Even if we avoid the trap of thinking you mean that $x',y'$ indicate derivatives, the notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ means that variable $x$ is varied *independently* of the *other implicit variables* of the function being differentiated.  But you are not explicit what function is being differentiated, and also not what variables including $x$ that function depends on.  By "playing games" with which variables are independent and which are dependent, one easily gets inconsistencies such as you found.

Answer (score 2):

When you are learning chain rule, it's better to be explicit about
which functions you are applying it to. Let's let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
and $g_{i}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions
for each $i=1,\ldots,n$. Define the function $h$ by
$$
h(x)=f(g_{1}(x),\ldots,g_{n}(x)).
$$
Then, the chain rule tells us how to get the derivative of $h$:
$$
h^{\prime}(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}(g_{1}(x))g_{1}^{\prime}(x)+\cdots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}}(g_{n}(x))g_{n}^{\prime}(x).
$$
In the above, we are using $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}$ to
denote the derivative of $f$ with respect to its $i$-th argument.

**Example**: Let $f(x_{1},x_{2})=(x_{1})^{3}+(x_{2})^{2}$. Let $g_{1}(x)=2x$
and $g_{2}(x)=\sin x$. Then,
$$
h(x)=f(g_{1}(x),g_{2}(x))=(2x)^{3}+(\sin x)^{2}.
$$
The chain rule tell us that
$$
h^{\prime}(x)=\underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}(g_{1}(x))}_{3(2x)^{2}}\underbrace{g_{1}^{\prime}(x)}_{2}+\underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{2}}(g_{2}(x))}_{2(\sin x)}\underbrace{g_{2}^{\prime}(x)}_{\cos x}.
$$

Comment: So for the above $x$, $y$, $x'$ and $y'$ the chain rule says that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -a\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}$ for all differentiable $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. But since $x'=x$. I have to conclude that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}=0$ for all such $f$. What is this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

The big problem beyond the confusing notation: when you say (implicitly):
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} =
\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}+\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'},
$$
the $f$ if the LHS is *different* of the $f$ in the RHS.

Using different names (I'm doing the same again, using the same name for the *variables* $x',y'$ and the *functions* $x',y'$):
$$f(x',y'),\qquad F(x,y) = f(x'(x,y),y'(x,y)),$$
we have now:
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} =
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x} =
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} - a\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'},
$$
and your problem vanishes because $F\ne f$.

Comment: In other words, partial differentiation is done on pairs of variables. We can't just think about partial derivatives on their lonesome, the entire set of variables matters. Otherwise, we face the confusion of the OP.